# Different __getstate__/__setstate__ for multiprocesing and pickling?

Tags: pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem. The classes i defined are passed to `multiprocessing.Pool()`'s during the computations. Then, i want to save thoose objects with `pickle.dump()` once all computations are done.

To ease computations, i pre-compute some things before sending the objects to the processes. Then, while saving to disk, theese precomputations are not necessary anymore, so i wanted to remove them using a `__setstate__`/`__getstate__` mecanism as recomanded by the `pickle` documentation.

**Q: Does the pickling done by `multiprocessing` uses the user-defined `__setstate__`/`__getstate__` ? If yes, how can i use different `__setstate__`/`__getstate__` for pickle and multiprocessing ?**

Indeed, my pre-computations are thrown away and re-done by each spawn process..

EDIT : I founded this : [multiprocessing ignores "__setstate__"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685329/multiprocessing-ignores-setstate) which treats a similar problem. The first answer shows differences between windows and linux behavior (which is problematic for me...). But this is 7 years old. What is the current implementation state on this matter ?